# A question on computational complexity of a numerical differentiation (equation (5.77)) in Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning

Tags: neural-networks, derivative, numerics, time-complexity, jacobian

In page 249 of Christopher M. Bishop's book "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", it is said

> Again, the implementation of such algorithms can be checked by using
> numerical differentiation in the form $$\frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x_i}=\frac{y_k(x_i+\epsilon)-y_k(x_i-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}+O(\epsilon^2)\tag{5.77}$$
> which involves $2D$ forward propagations for a network having $D$ inputs.

But I can see no relation of the computational complexity with $D$. According to the first paragraph of section 5.3.3 of the same book, my understanding is that the computation of (5.77) should involves $2W$ forward propagations for a network having $W$ weights, one for computing $y_k(x_i+\epsilon)$ while another for $y_k(x_i-\epsilon)$. Am I right? If the book is indeed correct, why does the numerical differentiation involve $2D$ forward propagations? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its talking about units of 1 full computation ie calculating an output for a given input.

To do the numerical differentiation
for each input feature you shift each feature by +/- epsilon (leaving other input features same) and calculate the resulting output
so you calculate over 2 x D input patterns.
eg with x_i = (1,0,0) then  eg (1+e, 0,0) (1-e,0,0), (0, 1+e,0), (0,1-e,0) , (0, 0, 1+e), (0,0, 1-e).